# ¿Como poner defaultValues en react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Lo que necesito hacer es algo sencillo, pero no me esta dando resultado. Traigo los datos de una api perfectamente guardándolos en **const [operation, setOperation] = React.useState([]);**.
Ahora, de mi hook **operation**, solo necesito los datos **"concept"** y **"amount"** para mostrarlos en sus respectivos **input** del **formulario**.
Mi **formulario** esta hecho con **useForm** de **react-hook-form** y **yup** para las **validaciones**, pero el **input concept y amount quedan vacios** cuando intento mostrar los datos, entonces cuando intento hacer el **submit** no me deja, porque al no tener declarados esos **valores por defecto** en el **useForm**, detecta que **hay campos vacios**. Entonces, ¿Por qué no se estan mostrando esos datos en los **input**?

Aca mi formulario mostrando los input vacios, y el **state de operation** con sus datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aca el codigo:

```js
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";
import OperationsService from "./../../../services/operationsService";
import CategoryService from "./../../../services/categoryService";

const EditOperation = () => {
    
  const [operation, setOperation] = React.useState([]);

  
React.useEffect(() => {
      getOperation();   
  }, []);

// aca traigo los datos de la api
 const getOperation = () => {
    const data = operationService.getOperation(id);
    data.then((res) => {
      setOperation(res);
    }
 }

 const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    // aca intento extraer de operation el valor de concept y amount para que queden por defecto en el formulario   
    defaultValues:{
        concept: operation.map(item => item.concept),
        amount:  operation.map(item => item.amount),
    }   
  });

const onSubmit = (formData, e) => {
     e.preventDefault();  
    // Aca Logica para editar operation
  }


  return(
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
    <div className="icon">
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPen} />
    </div>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="concept"
      {...register("concept")}
      placeholder="Concepto..."
      className="form-control" 
    />
  </div>

  <p className="text-center">
    <span className="small text-danger">{errors.concept?.message}</span>
  </p>

  <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
    <div className="icon">
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHandHoldingUsd} />
    </div>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="amount"
      {...register("amount")}
      placeholder="Monto"
      className="form-control"  
    />
  </div>

  <p className="text-center">
    <span className="small text-danger">{errors.amount?.message}</span>
  </p>

  <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
    <div className="icon">
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCalendarDay} />
    </div>
    <DataPicker
      selected={Date.parse(operation.map((item) => item.date))}
      dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
      onChange={onChangeDate}
      className="form-control"
      name="date"
    />
  </div>

  <div className="d-flex align-items-center mt-3">
    <label className="text-muted">Tipo:</label>
    <select
      className="form-select"
      value={operation.map((item) => item.type)}
      onChange={(e) => {
        const selectedType = e.target.value;
        setType(selectedType);
      }}
    >
      <option value="ingreso">Ingreso</option>
      <option value="egreso">Egreso</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div className="d-flex align-items-center mt-3">
    <label className="text-muted">Categoria:</label>
    <select
      className="form-select"
      onChange={(e) => {
        const selectedCategory = e.target.value;
        setIdCategory(selectedCategory);
      }}
    >
      <option
        selected
        key={operation.map((item) => item.category)}
        value={operation.map((item) => item.category)}
      >
        {catName}
      </option>

      {stateCategories.map((item) => (
        <option key={item.id} value={item.id}>
          {item.name}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  </div>

  <div className="d-grid gap-2">
    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mt-5">
      Editar
    </button>
  </div>
</form>;
 );

}
```

si le pongo los **valores por defecto** de esta forma los muestra, pero necesito que sean los valores **concept** y **amount** de **operation** .

```js
const {
    setValue,
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    defaultValues: {
      concept: "concepto 1",
      amount: 800
    },
  });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione de esta forma: **useForm** ofrece un método llamado **setValue("nombreInput", "value")** para poder setear los valores del **input**.

Entonces:

1. declaro **setValue** en el **useForm**:

```js
 const {
    register,
    setValue,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });
```

2. En la funcion **getOperations()** hago el **setValue** en los input:

```js
const getOperation = () => {
    const data = operationService.getOperation(id);
    data.then((res) => {
      setOperation(res);
      setType(res[0].type);
      // setting default values in inputs of the form
      setValue("concept", res[0].concept);
      setValue("amount", res[0].amount);
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo pude solucionar de la siguiente manera, pero claro los datos solo me iban a servir para mostar en un modal con los inputs desabilitados.

export const CustomerModal = ({ customerSelect }) => {

```
const form = useForm({
  mode: 'all',
});
useEffect(() => {
    form.setValue("name", customerSelect.name)
    form.setValue("lastname", customerSelect.lastname)
    form.setValue("email", customerSelect.email)
    form.setValue("telephone", customerSelect.telephone)
    form.setValue("active", true)
}, [customerSelect]);
```

};

De esta forma asigno por defecto los campos de los inputs correspondientes con datos que provienen de mi api pasados por props.